# getting all select inputs on a single page in the C# code behind file of ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

How would i go about getting all select inputs on a single page in the C# code behind file of ASP.NET ?

these select inputs are a part of a control, and the page contains several of the controls.

Comment: iterating through the page controls?

Comment: For this you have to get the HtmlSelect and the DropDownList controls.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that these controls are `runat="server"`, you want to use the [Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) collection on the page and, recursively, any container controls (HasControls is true for that control) that you find from the page.  Add any found control that matches the type you are interested in (DropDownList or HtmlSelect) to your list.  If the selects are not `runat="server"`, then I think you're out of luck unless their naming gives them away.  You can't tell the type of an HTML input from the contents of the Form collection.

```
public List<Control> FindSelects( Control control, List<Control> controls )
{
     if (control is DropDownList or control is HtmlSelect)
     {
          controls.Add( control );
     }
     else if (control.HasControls)
     {
          foreach (var subcontrol in control.Controls)
          {
               controls = FindSelects( subcontrol, controls );
          }
     }
     return controls;
}
```

Comment: Looks great. Do note that this will not get the "SELECT" input of non-server controls. I.e. those <select> elemets without "runat=server".